# When creating a table I got this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have an issue when creating a new table.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE 'pendaftar' (
    'id' int(10) NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'tgl' DATE NOT NULL,
    'nopol' VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    'motor' VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    'servis' VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    'keluhan' LONGTEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

The error message I receive is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near ''pendaftar' ('id' int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'tgl' DATE NOT
>   NUL' at line 1

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: don't use quotes to escape table or column names. Remove them or use backticks instead

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks#11321508)

Comment: my bad.. i use quote instead of bactick. Thanks for the answer, very appriciate it